# New tap is incredibly noisy, can I fix that?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, sink

Plumber changed my bathroom sink (and toilet & shower too). The old sink from the 70s had 2 taps - cold + hot, and it was silent. New sink has a single tap and is insanely noisy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzL-z-RXgwY. It doesn't render well in the video but in reality the noise is profound, and you can hear it in the whole house.

What causes such huge difference and can a plulmber easily fix it?

Comment: Try closing the shutoffs under the sink a bit to reduce the flow. Make sure the aerator is clean.

Comment: Thanks, I told that to the plumber but it made no difference. He said hot water and cold water come at different strengths and one is trying to overcome the other - or something like that. And that's what creates so much noise apparently.

Comment: Did you, he, try it adjusting the shutoffs?  The different strengths is misleading because your water main splits to feed your cold water and feed your hot water heater. The strengths should be close to equal, they are not having a tug-of-war.

Comment: This guy isn't a good professional, each thing he did in my bathroom has some problem in it. So you might well be right.